# Unable to render autocomplete component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to display following component for completion. My other component works fine but this one won't render. It is not showing any error. I used Angular material

Here is the code:

autocomplete.component.html

```
<form class="cities-form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Gradovi</mat-label>
        <input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="Izaberi"
        aria-label="Izaberi grad"
        matInput
        [formControl]="searchTerm"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>

        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let city of filteredCities | async"
            [value]="city"> {{city}}</mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

autocomplete.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.css']
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  searchTerm = new FormControl();

  cities: string[] = ['Novi Sad', 'Beograd', 'Nis'];

  filteredCities!: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredCities = this.searchTerm.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value:string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.cities.filter(city => city.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

}
```

app.component.html (my-map is other component that is rendering)

```
<h1>Geoapify Map</h1>
<my-map></my-map>
<app-autocomplete></app-autocomplete>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

//Material Components
import { MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map/map.component';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { AutocompleteComponent } from './autocomplete/autocomplete/autocomplete.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MapComponent,
    AutocompleteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DataService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what do you see if you inspect the DOM in the browser?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the DOM inspect. (I can't upload a picture to my post, that's why I am posting a link): https://imgur.com/a/WIWhoQJ

Comment: looks like the element is rendered but not visible. Probably it's a CSS problem